# Extend partition using LVM

Tags: partition, hard-disk, lvm

I have Ubuntu 16.04 (no desktop manager installed) running in vmware. I am out of space and am trying to extend the existing partition using LVM. I have added additional space in vmware but am having trouble adding it to ubuntu.

This is the guide I am following: [Expand a Hard Disk with Ubuntu LVM](http://www.geoffstratton.com/expand-hard-disk-ubuntu-lvm).

I am stuck on the part where I need to add a physical volume. This is the command, and output im getting:

```
root@ubuntu:~# pvcreate /dev/sda3
Device /dev/sda3 not found (or ignored by filtering).
```

I can see my partitions, but can't understand why its not finding it. Here's the output of my partitions:

```
root@ubuntu:~# fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 75 GiB, 80530636800 bytes, 157286400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x277beceb

Device Boot Start End Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1 * 2048 999423 997376 487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2 1001470 20969471 19968002 9.5G 5 Extended
/dev/sda3 20969472 157286399
136316928 65G 83 Linux
/dev/sda5 1001472 20969471 19968000 9.5G 8e Linux LVM
```

My current 10G drive is /sda5 and /sda3 is the new partition with 65 gb im trying to add to it.

This is what the filter in my lvn.conf looks like - if its commented out,  this isn't the issue, right?

```
# global_filter = [ "a|.*/|" ]
```

Comment: Try `sudo /sbin/partprobe` to (from the man page) *inform the OS of partition table changes*.

Comment: Wow - that did the job.  If you make it the answer, I can accept it as the solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you update the partition information in a running linux system, you need to inform the operating system kernel; the usual way to do so is with `partprobe`

> sudo /sbin/partprobe

From the [`partprobe(8)` man](https://linux.die.net/man/8/partprobe) page,

> **partprobe** is a program that informs the operating system kernel of partition table changes, by requesting that the operating system re-read the partition table.